# How to convert a number over a JavaBean and send it back to a JSP page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am making a simple program that consists of a HTML page, JSP page and a JavaBean.
The HTML page is used to let the user input the data. The JSP then sends the data to the JavaBean which is supposed to convert the value from inches to centimeters using the equation 1 inch = 2.54 cm. I however cannot get it to work. Am I missing something or doing something wrong. Please help.

The HTML page

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Input an Inch</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:lightblue">

<center>
    <form action="DisplayJSP.jsp">
        Input an inch value:<input type="text" name="clientValue">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</center>

</body>
```

The JSP page

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Results</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:lightblue">

<center>

<jsp:useBean id="convertBean" class="unit4.MBean" scope="session">
    <jsp:setProperty name="convertBean" property="myInches" param="clientValue" />
</jsp:useBean>

<jsp:getProperty name="convertBean" property="myInches" />
inches = 
<jsp:getProperty name="convertBean" property="myCentimeters" />
cm
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

And finally the JavaBean

```
package unit4;

import java.io.*;

public class MBean implements Serializable {

private double myInches;
private double myCentimeters;

public MBean() {
    myCentimeters = myInches * 2.45;
}

public void setMyInches(double tempInches) {
    this.myInches = tempInches;
}

public double getMyInches() {
    return myInches;
}

public double getMyCentimeters() {
    return myCentimeters;
}
}
```

Comment: What does _cannot get it to work_ mean?  Is there a compile or runtime error?

Comment: the is no error, I just cannot get my centimeter result to display

Answer (score 0):

The default method of form is `get`, I think you should try to use `post`, eg:

```
  <form action="DisplayJSP.jsp" method="post">
```